# I have Makefile syntax problem on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: makefile

I created Makefile with next command:

```
cli:
    docker run --rm -v ${PWD}/manager:/app --workdir=/app php:7.2-cli php bin/index.php
```

And when I run `make cli`
I have the next problem 
`/home/viktor/Documents/PhpProjects/project.com/Makefile:2: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.`

I tried to google problem. But I have no idea how to resolve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two hits for a general approach to debugging:

- look hard at the error message
- simplify your example down to the point where you see the problem

The error message points to line 2.
So I'd simplify line 2 and check whether the error persists:

```
cli:
    echo foo
```

The errors does persist, so there's still a problem with line 2.

Solution: You have to put a tab character in front on line 2.

Comment: You code worked! But I need to run my code and have error near ':'

Comment: Is _I have error near ':'_ the best problem description that you can provide?